# Separable first order DE relating to a rhinoceros population

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question I am stuck on.  I believe it is a separable first order DE which seems super hard to 'solve the system exactly' for $R(t)$.

The equation is:
$$\frac{\operatorname d R}{\operatorname dt}=\frac{1}{5}R(2-R);\quad R(0)=0.5$$

Anybody have any suggestions?  I think it involves using partial fractions.

Cheers :)

Comment: Try integrating ${1 \over R (2-R)} {dR \over dt} = {1 \over 5}$ on both sides over the interval $[0,t]$.

Answer (score 1):

You've stated that this is a separable diff.eq. so I assume that you know that you should get the terms dependent only on R on one side and then integrate. So your task is to integrate the following.
$$\frac{R'}{R(2-R)} = \frac{1}{5}$$

Ok but how does one integrate such a monster? Well, you've also said that you think it involves partial fractions, so write the left hand side as a sum of partial fractions, then realize that you have basically already solved the task. :) Of course don't forget to set the constant according to $R(0)$.

If you get stuck somewhere, leave a comment or update your question and someone will help you out.

Comment: But dont you have to take the whole entire right hand side of the equation to the left and you are left with just dt on the right hand side?

Comment: That's just notational difference. :) You are in fact supposed to find the antiderivative of both sides. if it were $\frac{f'}{f} = 5$, then taking the antiderivative of both sides would result in $log(f(t)) = 5t + c$ where c is some arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 0):

**Separable DE**:

If I have read the question correctly,  the DE is as follows:

$\frac{dR}{dt}=\frac{1}{5R(2-R)}$,  where $R(0)=0.5$.

The DE can be re-written by grouping all terms in $R$ with $dR $:

$ 5R(2-R) \frac{dR}{dt}=1$

Giving us the integral solution:

$\int 5R(2-R) \mathrm{d}R=\int \mathrm{d}t + C$

where C is the integration constant.

Comment: the R(2-R) is on the numerator not the denominator :)

Comment: So, dR/dt=R(2-R)/5; R(0)=0.5

Comment: Okay,  then I agree with @Andrew 's answer and comment.